# Reactjs: How to Access Context from a submitHandler?

Tags: reactjs, forms, callback, react-hooks, react-context

Please tell me if I'm approaching this from the wrong angle.

I have a class component `App` which has many generations of child components. Many grandchild components will need access to an `inventory` database, so I have opted to use Context to store this database.

A brief excerpt from `App`'s constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.itemAdd=this.itemAdd.bind(this);
        let tempinventory = baseinventory;
        //append our itemAdd function to the context
        tempinventory.itemAdd = this.itemAdd;
        this.state={
          inventory:tempinventory,
        }
        ...
      }
```

Notice that here I'm adding the function `itemAdd` to the context so that grandchildren can call on this function without me needing to prop-drill that callback all the way down.

One grandchild component `ItemAddForm` will need to manage a form with many fields and will need to pass the form's contents into `itemAdd` when the Submit button is pressed. I'm at a loss for how to accomplish this, since keeping track of the form's contents seems to necessitate that `ItemAddForm` be a stateful class component, but class components are unable to access Context outside of the render method as far as I am aware.

Here's how I would *like* to do this:

```
class ItemAddForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitHandler=this.submitHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = defaultstate;
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]:value,
    });
  }

  submitHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let item=this.state;
    this.Context.itemAdd(item);
    document.getElementById("InventoryAddForm").reset();
    this.setState(defaultstate);
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <form 
            onSubmit={this.submitHandler}
            id="InventoryAddForm"
          >
          <input
            name="price"
            className="FormField"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          ...
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But clearly that doesn't work because this.Context is undefined. Do I strictly need to turn `ItemAddForm` into a functional component that monitors the form context purely through hooks? How should I go about this proper?

Comment: `itemAdd` if you are passing that as a prop then you would just call `this.props.itemAdd()` directly. Since you are using `Context` reference in your question, not sure if you meant to use React's Context API

Comment: I am using React's Context API. I pass `itemAdd` down as Context instead of a prop because I want to avoid passing this prop from grandparent to parent to the child form which uses it.

Comment: Are you importing Context and assigning it to your class? `MyClass.contextType = MyContext;` Or Are you using Provider/Consumer pattern

Comment: I'm using the Provider/Consumer pattern simply because I hadn't found the `MyClass.contextType` way of doing things.

Comment: Hmm, I dont see Consumer related code in your `ItemAddForm` component.

Comment: I don't see any way to implement it. That's ultimately what brings me to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code to use Context Consumer pattern. Context's Consumer wraps a callback which gives you access to all that was passed within Context's `Provider` as `<MyContext.Provider value={/* some value */}>`

```
import MyContext from '../my-desired-grandparent-provider';

class ItemAddForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitHandler=this.submitHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = defaultstate;
    this.renderContext = null;
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]:value,
    });
  }

  submitHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let item=this.state;
    this.renderContext.itemAdd(item);
    document.getElementById("InventoryAddForm").reset();
    this.setState(defaultstate);
  }

  renderForm = (value) => (<div>
          <form 
            onSubmit={this.submitHandler}
            id="InventoryAddForm"
          >
          <input
            name="price"
            className="FormField"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          ...
          </form>
        </div>)

  render(){
    return(
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {value => {
          this.renderContext = value;
          return this.renderForm(value);
        }}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```